# Can we use definite article "the" with meal of the day?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I have a question about using definite article. I'm Azerbaijanian that's why I don't know English grammar very well. In English lesson our topic was "Article". And I wanna know can I use "the" with "lunch", "breakfast" or "dinner"

Comment: Commonly yes...

Answer (score 0):

When we think of meal as a process, not as an event, we use no article.

For example,
*How was the dinner?*

In this case, "the dinner" often refers to the meal as an event.

*How was dinner?*

In this case, "dinner" simply refers to an evening meal.

So if there's a special event use "the" otherwise simply use:

*How was dinner last night?*

Or

*How was your dinner last night?*